# SQliteQueueDatabase UPDATE delays?

Tags: python, peewee

Any reason why Peewee SQliteQueue UPDATE take "some" time to be applied to database?

Here's my debug log:

```
2019-10-15 22:50:16,933 - peewee.sqliteq                   (a68) :  DEBUG (sqliteq:176) - received query UPDATE "table_episodes" SET "subtitles" = ? WHERE ("table_episodes"."path" = ?)
2019-10-15 22:50:16,934 - peewee                           (a68) :  DEBUG (peewee:2993) - ('UPDATE "table_episodes" SET "subtitles" = ? WHERE ("table_episodes"."path" = ?)', [u"[['en', u'/some_path.en.srt']]", u'/some_path'])
2019-10-15 22:50:16,946 - peewee                           (1254) :  DEBUG (peewee:2993) - ('SELECT "t1"."subtitles" FROM "table_episodes" AS "t1" WHERE ("t1"."sonarrSeriesId" = ?)', [156])
```

I'm expecting the SELECT to pickup the new value from the `subtitles` column but in fact it return the previous value that was `u'[]'`.

If I open the database with a SQlite browsing tool I can see the new value. Any idea?

Comment: @coleifer any hint for me? Some cache parameter maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Probably has to do with isolation between the connections. The UPDATE may not be committed, so the connection doing the read doesn't see it yet?

Comment: thanks for your feedback! When peewee log the second line in my debug log, shouldn't it been committed before logging it?